# Is there an application or a log that tracks apps/processes that were running just before an unexpected shutdown

Tags: 11.04, log, process

It's very helpful that browsers and various document readers remember their pre-crash states, but is there a way for ubuntu to do this? If I have a bunch of apps open, is that "app state" stored anywhere?

Comment: Not sure but have a look at this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man5/core.5.html I think those get created when there is a crash but I never got to play with these under Linux so I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

No, the list of running apps/processes is stored on memory and lost with the shutdown.

Comment: Does a `core`-dump not what he is asking?

Comment: No, a core dump will give you the memory content of one application when that application crashes (and only in some circumstances). An unexpected shutdown will just close all running applications.